# Sysprep question

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sysprep

I want to move a VHD I have on my Hyper-V server to another Hyper-V server I am setting up. For this to happen, does the VHD need to be sysprepped?

Furthermore, I am downloading an OVF of a VM I have on an ESX hypervisor and want to open this in VMWare Workstation 7.0. This VM is on a domain and has a static IP. I assume it needs sysprepping. However, can I sysprep it while it loads or can this only be done from inside the OS? The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2. All I really need to do is clean it of its domain information and IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're *moving* a VHD, no it does not. If you're *copying*, probably yes (though it will depend on what exactly you're doing). Most prepared VHDs etc that you download (like a demo from a company) are ready to run the way they are.

If you just need to strip the domain/IP configuration from the image, boot it up, login and configure it. No need to sysprep.

Comment: What's the difference in moving/copying?

Comment: Seriously? If you move a file, it's no longer in the original location. If you copy you now have the same file in multiple locations. You have to sysprep an image if multiple instances of it will be run.